# Codeigniter : How can remove any error message for user

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have problem in link of my script by Codeigniter.
I have this URL :-

```
localhost/index.php/details/1
```

Its get me all details of product, by `ID` , But when i add any character in the end of link like this :

```
localhost/index.php/details/ggg
```

The user see some error message.

How can save my link, And hidden this message.

Comment: You should simply redirect every kind of these errors to your 404 page, and that's it, because you can't control every string the user try to attach to your url from the address bar.

Comment: And addition to @Masiorama comment you'll find it at `application/errors/error_404.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Method 01**

in `config/routs.php`

```
$route['404_override'] = 'Controller name';//this to avoid 404 Error
```

**Method 02**

in your controller check empty

```
$data['product'] = $this->Model_Name->get_product($id);

if(empty( $data['product']))
    {
        $this->empty_result();
    }
    else
    {
        //load relevent view
    }
```

*In controller* at top create function call `empty_result()`

```
public function empty_result()
{

    $this->load->view('template/header');
    $this->load->view('template/right_sidebar');
    $this->load->view('template/NothingFound',$data);//create a page to show empty or Nothing found
    $this->load->view('template/foot');
}
```

*In Model*

```
public function get_product($id)
{
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM product WHERE id ='$id'");
    $result = $query->result_array();
    return $result;
}
```

*In view* (template/NothingFound.php)

create file call `NothingFound.php`

in that

```
<h1>No thing found title</h1>
<!--customize the view as you want. Add some images-->
```

**EDIT 01**

**Method 03**

Goto `error/error_404.php`

[image: 404 Error]

Edit the error message to display in your styles

Comment: Good,, But when visit `localhost/index.php/details/ggg` i dont see 404 not found page, what can do ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82589/discussion-between-abdulla-and-zamalek-man).

Answer (score 0):

you can easily do this using 404 page .

in your routes.php file find the line :
$route['404_override'] = '';
in single quotation add contrller/ action method . in this method add view 404 page design . then when any error occured your user see the 404 error page